# How can we choose the distance between PlotMarkers in a ListPlot?

Tags: plotting

If we write in *Mathematica*:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{x, x^4}, {x, 1, 2, 0.03}], Joined -> True,
PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 10}]
```

we get:

[image]

where there is a marker in each point of the table.

How can we do in order to choose the number of markers or their separation (without eliminate table points)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{x, x^4}, {x, 1, 2, 0.03}],
 Joined -> True,
 Mesh -> 4,
 PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 10}]
```

[image]

Specify at particular x-positions

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{x, x^4}, {x, 1, 2, 0.03}],
 Joined -> True,
 Mesh -> {{1.2, 1.8}},
 PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 10}]
```

[image]

or at particular y-positions

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{x, x^4}, {x, 1, 2, 0.03}],
 Joined -> True,
 Mesh -> {{5, 10}},
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &},
 PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! But this solution make a equidistant mesh and in LogPlots whit more range in the Log axe, all the PlotMarkers are in one zone of the curve. How can we solve this cases? Sorry, I do not put images in comments.

Comment: Thanks another time! Very useful information.